# В gulp/webpack какой-то модуль ставит лишние пробелы в 0\\0 для @media

Tags: gulp, сборка, media-queries, stylus

В проекте с gulp/webpack какой-то модуль ставит пробелы в 0\0 для @media для запроса @media all and (min-width:0\0) and (min-resolution:.001dpcm)

Стиль написан на stylus.

Т.е. в .css после сборки попадает

```
@media all and (min-width: 0 \ 0) and (min-resolution: 0.001dpcm) {
```

а 0 \ 0 не работает в результате. Какой модуль может добавляеть эти пробелы, можно как-то их убрать, или заставить принять строку кода строго, как написано?

вот часть устаеовленых модулей в проекте:

```
    "eslint-loader": "^1.1.1",
    "gulp-combine-mq": "^0.4.0",
    "gulp-cssnano": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-filter": "^3.0.1",
    "gulp-group-css-media-queries": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-stylint": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-stylus": "^2.1.0",
    "merge-stream": "^1.0.0",
    "stylint-stylish": "^1.2.0",
    "stylus": "^0.54.5",
```

Comment: Можно отключить сначала половину всех плагинов, затем половину из половины, и дойти до виновника.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45814394/873481

Вы можете использовать @css, что бы не дать stylus изменить ваше правило:

```
@css{
  @media all and (min-width:0\0) and (min-resolution:.001dpcm){
    // здесь ваш css код
  }
}
```

и получаете точно это:

```
 @media all and (min-width:0\0) and (min-resolution:.001dpcm){
   // здесь ваш css код
 }
```

Так же Вы можете использовать интерполяцию:

```
@media all and ({"min-width:0\0"}) and (min-resolution:.001dpcm)
```